# Не работает программа С++

Tags: c++, циклы, while

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include<iomanip>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Ukrainian");
    int k, a1, a2, a3,a4, i;             
    k = 0;
    i = 999;
    while (i < 10000)
    {
        do
        {
            i += 1;
            a1 = i / 100;
            a2 = i % 100;
            
        } while (a1 != a2);
        cout << i <<" "<<k++ << endl;
    }
    
    cout << "Кількість чотирьохзначних чисел, що представляють собою повторювані фрагменти послідовності цифр, дорівнює: " << k << endl;
}
```

Условие:
Найти все четырехзначные числа, представляющие собой повторяющиеся
фрагменты последовательности цифр (например, 1212, 4545) и их количество.

То есть программа вывводит все нужные числа и номер
но не показывает конечный вывод, оно как будто зависает и проводится очень долгая диагностика.
Если заменить этот вывод в цикле на простой расчет К++, как мне и нужно, программа вообще не будет ничего выводить.

**я знаю что можно было использовать только if в for, но мне нужно сделать программу именно со вложенным циклом.*

Answer (score 2):

Во вложенном цикле вы находите последнее число `i == 9999`, после чего продолжаете работу в том же цикле, но уже с пятизначными числами, а поскольку больше такого числа вы не найдете, цикл будет крутиться до переполнения и прихода к числу 1010 снизу :)

Непонятно, зачем вам вложенный цикл вообще, но если уж так хочется чесать левое ухо правой рукой, проведя ее под левой ногой — то замените `} while (a1 != a2);` на

```
} while (a1 != a2 && i < 10000);
```

и соответствующим образом подправьте следующую за ней строку вывода — выводить только при `a1 == a2`.

Comment: учим сейчас сложные циклы, поэтому и нужно использовать вложенный. Спасибо за помощь